# upgrade from postgres 12 to 13 causes user authority problem

Tags: postgresql, authorization, upgrade

I have a windows install of postgres 12.6-1 installed at port 6432. I have installed a newer version at port 9432 to test the database against our application.

Firstly I tried to dump globals from the 12 to sql, and install the user list into the 13. This was a disaster as all the users including the superuser now were inaccessible.

So I read the release notes, and it say to use pg_upgrade. After a lot of pain, I get it to run, but it appears to have just run the pg_dumpall like I did.
pg_upgrade failed at the point of generating databases as the local super user, because the user load has damaged the passwords and now the database cannot be accessed again.

I have checked the SQL output from the PG_DUMPALL command with and without --binary-upgrade, and it appears to be identical in it's generation of MD5 hash data from the database.

Do I need another tool?

An I doing something wrong?

The 13 database is empty, so any drastic action would be ok.

Comment: So to be clear you did `pg_dumpall -g -f some_file` and then `psql -f some_file -d new_db`? Define '...as all the users including the superuser now were inaccessible.` I do this sort of thing all the time without a problem, so there must a hitch in your procedure somewhere.

Comment: command line and internally within pg_upgrade both did command: pg_dumpall -U postgres -g -p <sourcedbport>  -f somefile.sql.  File generates series of SQL commands to add users using *password 'md5xxxxxxxxx'* syntax. Both times the SQL appeared to be loaded correctly, but when the user is referenced for a create statement the password is rejected. Confirmed this by trying to use command line psql -p newdbport -U postgres postgres. Postgres user id same password in both dbs is rejected.

Comment: Look in the log file for v13 for the error messages you get while logging in, and show them to us.  Most likely v13's pg_hba is configured to only allow SCRAM authentication, which means you can't use the old MD5 password hashes to log in anymore.  You would either have to upgrade all the users' passwords (by resetting them, there is no way to automatically upgrade in place), or revert back to allowing md5

Comment: Backing up @jjanes comment. Generally `scram-sha-256` did not become the default `password_encryption` until Postgres 14. I now remember from a past question that EDB(which I assume is where you got the installer) jumped the gun and made it the default in Postgres 13.

Answer (score 1):

The ED 13 installation defaults the pg_hba.conf encryption to scram-sha-256. If you have loaded passwords with this encryption, keep it. If you (like me) unknowingly loaded md5 encrypted passwords, just change the encryption to md5 on the lines for pg_hba.conf and restart postgres.

If you wish to keep the scram-sha-256 encryption level, Then I suspect there is no alternative but to edit the pg_dumpall output and change the syntax to plain text password entry, and reset the passwords on the new db. I know this works because I just tried loading a sample of the file with plain text password, and was able to log in as the new user.

Thanks to Adrian Klaver and jjanes.